# Weird conflict with deploy of django project with django_assets

Tags: django, wsgi

recently I've tried to add webassets to my django project. All goes without any problem in development (with django runserver). All js and css are beign compressed when I set the settings var ASSETS_DEBUG to False.

The problem arises when I browse my project from my deployed structure (apache + mod_wsgi). An exception is raised from django_assets giving me the following message:

RegisterError: Another bundle is already registered as "js_all": ], contents=('js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js', 'js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js', 'js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js', 'js/ui.datepicker-es.js', 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', 'js/tiny_mce_config.js', 'js/public.js')>

Can't find the reason for this exception, not thrown in development. Following is my assets file:

```
from django_assets import Bundle, register
js = Bundle(
    'js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js',
    'js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js',
    'js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js',
    'js/ui.datepicker-es.js',
    'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
    'js/tiny_mce_config.js',
    'js/public.js',
    filters='yui_js',
    output='js/gen/packed.js'
    )
register('js_all', js)

css = Bundle(
    'css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css',
    'css/jquery_ui_fixes.css',
    'css/public.css',
    'css/forms.css',
    filters='yui_css',
    output='css/gen/packed.css',
    )
register('css_all', css)
```

Webassets version used is the one in pip repository:
**version** = (0, 6)

I hope that somebody will be able to help me.

Isaac

Comment: are you sure this isn't getting imported twice?  Try commenting out the register('js_all', js) and see if you get a second error for the 'css_all'

Answer (score 2):

Because of some silliness with Django, your settings.py file can be imported twice. Thus registration will occur twice. Read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html

for all the horrible details of this issue.

Comment: Maybe it is good to add to your answer that because of this sillyness, you'll have to catch the RegisterError with a try except block around the register call.

Comment: In recent Django versions this double import shouldn't be an issue unless you yourself are triggering it in some way.